# Get ABI code for an ethereum contract event

Tags: events, abi

How can I construct the ABI code for a contract event?

I don't need the whole contract ABI.

Example:

- transferFrom(address,address,uint256)
- executeMetaTransaction(address,bytes,bytes32,bytes32,uint8)

I need to get the ABI code for events like this.

Should I just create a basic contract with the event in Remix and compile it?

Comment: I just used this to get encoded data. Using the event + parameters and inputting data from a txn from the contract.

Is there any way to get the ABI json from the encoded data?

https://abi.hashex.org/

Comment: just `keccak` the string `transferFrom(address,address,uint256)` and you will get the "abi code" which is just a hash. this is how it is done by Geth: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/241cf62b5c8b70b1a4206587fa42606ad5de024a/accounts/abi/event.go#L88

Answer (score 1):

You can get the whole ABI via Etherscan API and then via for loop filter out only the event related part.

Here is a snippet from a Python code on how to do it:

```
# contract ABI extraction via Etherscan API
events = []
etherscan_url = f'https://api-goerli.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address={contract_address}&apikey={etherscan_api}'
etherscan_response = requests.get(etherscan_url)
etherscan_content = etherscan_response.json()
contract_abi = etherscan_content.get("result")
contract_abi_dict = json.loads(contract_abi)
print(f"ABI: {contract_abi}")

# Event name extraction
for i, j in enumerate(contract_abi_dict):
    if contract_abi_dict[i]['type'] == "event":
        events.append(contract_abi_dict[i]['name'])
        print(contract_abi_dict[i]['name'])
```

Comment: I'm looking at a contract on Polygonscan that doesn't have their Contract verified so can't do this.

Comment: You will need to get the code itself and once compiled in Remix for example, you can get the ABI manually.